# Softlayer API - Custom Hardware_Component_Partition_Template

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

My team is trying to order Baremetal Servers with RAID configurations through the API.

We are running into trouble with not having enough Swap space on the primary storage group where the OS is installed.
We are able to specify a Partition Template ID to use for the primary partition, but none of these existing templates have enough swap space.
We would like to have 100 GB of swap space available in our partition.

After reading some documentation, I get the impression that we are able to create CUSTOM partition templates but I am unable to
find out how to add a custom partition, namely with the following partition sizes:

```
"data": [
{
"isGrow": "True",
"name": "/",
"size": 1
},
{
"isGrow": "False",
"name": "/swap0",
"size": 100
},
{
"isGrow": "False",
"name": "/boot",
"size": 0.25
}
]
```

Would you be able to tell us how we can create a custom partition, or if this is not possible, how would I request a custom partition from softlayer?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look this forum [Configuring Softlayer Disk Partitions at Order Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35486839/configuring-softlayer-disk-partitions-at-order-time)

But keep in mind that the custom partitions are only available for the second configuration storage, for the first configuration storage you only can select a partition template ID.

Also you can ask for a partition template, you need to submit a ticket in Softlayer's Portal for that.

Regards

Comment: Hello, I submitted a partition template request on softlayer - and nobody has been able to create a partition template for me. Is it indeed possible to ask for a partition template, and if so, how could I get into contact with someone who has the knowledge to help me with that?

Comment: well that weird what I know the employees are capable to create partitions templates which should be available for you at moment to order. the only way is to submit a ticket and ask them.